# 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value (HY000)

Tags: laravel

ErrorException (E_WARNING)
imagettftext(): Invalid font filename

Comment: Can you add the code where you are adding the new user?

Comment: Looks like you're creating a new user without setting a value for `username`.

Comment: check your model, in `protected $fillable=[];` add username and other field of your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**username** is required field in your database schema, so every entry as a row in your database must include username and other required fields. Add username to the entry and it should work fine.